# Link message by message_id via telegram bot

Tags: telegram

I'm writing a simple bot and I want to basically link together two messages. I found that I could link one by replying on it, so it works like a charm. But now I want to insert a link to another message. And here is a problem, the only way to make a link I found is post link like `https://t.me/{chat_name}/{message_id}`. But it doesn't work for chats that don't have `chat_name`.

How could it be done?

Comment: There have no solution so far :(

Comment: How about forwarding the message?

Comment: @AlanBirtles bot shouldn't spam so I see it like `[reply to a message] this message looks just like [link to another message]`

Comment: Have you found a solution or a workaround yet? @AlexZhukovskiy

Comment: @fabio.sang if your chat is public then you could use `t.me` workaround. If it's not, then you can't refer it.

Comment: In some chats you can also link to a message with `t.me/c/chat_id/message_id` , but it seems this is also possible only in public chats

Answer (score 8):

Usually worked this pattern: `https://t.me/c/{chat_id}/{message_id}`, but it worked for me when I sliced `chat_id` (skipping minus and first 3 digits). For example on JS: `message.chat.id.toString().slice(4)`.

So, for message with `chat_id: -1001473943182` and `message_id: 5` link would be: `https://t.me/c/1473943182/5`.

But it work only for `chat.type = 'supergroup'` as I see and chat must have join link probably.

Comment: Sounds weird, but I'd try it. Thanks

Comment: @MrModest, thank you, it works. Idk what exactly makes a group a supergroup but I guess it's having more than one admin with a whole lot of rights.

Comment: @hey for supergroup you need to change one or more default permission for all users, for example "Change group info", as I now